# Why won't this Karma/Jasmine test catch a reference error?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following code that sorts books by their title:

```
function alphabetizeBookNodes(a, b) {
  if (typeof a.title !== "undefined") {
    var aTitle = _removeArticles(a.title.toLowerCase()),
        bTitle = _removeArticles(b.title.toLowerCase());
  } else {
    var aTitle = _removeArticles(a.book.title.toLowerCase()),
        bTitle = _removeArticles(b.book.title.toLowerCase());
  }

  if (aTitle > bTitle) return 1;
  if (aTitle < bTitle) return -1; 
  return 0;
}

function _removeArticles(str) {
  words = str.split(" ");
  if(words.length <= 1) return str;
  if( words[0] == 'a' || words[0] == 'the' || words[0] == 'an' ) { 
    return words.splice(1).join("");
  }
  return str;
}

module.exports = {alphabetizeBookNodes: alphabetizeBookNodes};
```

In the browser, the line `words = str.split(" ");` throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: words is not defined`. It should be `let words = ...`.

I'm trying to trigger that error using a Karma/Jasmine test, like so:

```
describe("Utils", function() { 
  it('compares books by removing articles from the title', function() { 
    let alphabetizeBookNodes = require('../utils').alphabetizeBookNodes;

    const bookA = {'title': 'The Grapes of Wrath'};
    const bookB = {'title': 'Huckleberry Finn'};

    let compare = function(a, b) { 
      return alphabetizeBookNodes(a, b);
    } 

    let books = [bookB, bookA];
    let sortedBooks = books.sort(compare);

    expect(sortedBooks.length).toEqual(2);
    expect(sortedBooks[0]).toEqual(bookA);
    expect(sortedBooks[1]).toEqual(bookB);
  });
});
```

Why isn't this test triggering the `ReferenceError`? How can I rewrite this test so that it will catch this error that users are experiencing in the browser?

Comment: do you have `'use strict';` at the top of your js file ? Only strict mode throws errors for operations on non-declared variables

Comment: @Arkantos no - would that go at the top of the function file or the test file?

Comment: @Arkantos your comment got me there - added `'use strict`;` to my utils.js file and it works, thank you!

Comment: You can use `toThrow()` matcher to assert if a method is throwing any error or some specific error like - `expect(your-method).toThrowError(ReferenceError);`

Comment: It's ok to validate if some method is throwing some errors while executing your code, but cases like yours should be corrected by declaring all the variables in proper scope before you start operating on them.